# What is Name meaning for Belinda

Tags: meaning

My name is *Belinda*. In my locality, it is a rare name. So, everyone asks for its meaning. I know that it is the heroine name of "Rape of the lock". When i googled, I found that it has the meaning of a **Serpent**. Really I felt bad about it. Did anyone give a serpent name to a child?. Or Whether it has any other meaning...

Please clarify

Comment: Did you Google "belinda name meaning"?

Comment: Belinda is a feminine given name of unknown origin, apparently coined from Italian bella, meaning "beautiful" (WP). Search and find many more interesting trivia about your name, Belinda.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is a name that has an obscure origin, and may have spontaneously originated in multiple cultures with different meanings.

For example it can be double name with latin roots.  Bella and linda in Italian mean beautiful and clean respectively.  (In Spanish linda means cute instead of clean.)

Alternatively, it can be derived from a Germanic root meaning "Bright serpent" or even "Bright Linden Tree".

To be honest, I would lean toward the Latin origin.  It's certainly a lot nicer!

Sources:
[Wikipedia-Belinda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belinda)
[Wikipedia-Linda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linda_%28name%29)
Educated guessing

Comment: A pleasure.  Sorry I could not provide a definitive answer.

Comment: I would go for Spanish: bella linda -> Belinda

Comment: @mplungjan I understand that, but I believe the clean in this case refers more to purity than physical cleanliness.

Comment: Bella Linda in Spanish means pretty, pretty so no need for cleanliness

Comment: @mplungjan I do not see them as mutually exclusive.  The name is used in both languages, which both have a common Latin root.  It seems likely that the name predates the formalization of either language.

Answer (score 2):

My name is Belinda as well. I have a 1974 edition of Funk and Wagnalls Encyclopedic Dictionary with name meanings and origins. 
**Belinda**  Serpent: Title of an oracular priestess. (Germanic). 
Remember that that your personal opinions and ideas about snakes may be completely different than the culture which this association comes from.